# Transform String = List<String> Map in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a map in terraform where the keys are strings and the values are a list of strings. It looks something like:

```
locals {
  admin_account_ids_by_team_name = {
    "foobar" = ["12345", "67890"]
  }
}
```

I need to transform this into something like:

```
{
  "foobar-12345" = { account_id = "12345", team_name = "foobar" }
  "foobar-67890" = { account_id = "67890", team_name = "foobar" }
}
```

Playing around in a `terraform console` I've been able to get something close using: `flatten([for team, account_ids in { "foobar" = ["12345", "67890"] } : [for account_id in account_ids : map("${account_id}-${team}", { account_id = account_id, team = team})]])`

This however gives me:

```
[
  {
    "12345-foobar" = {
      "account_id" = "12345"
      "team" = "foobar"
    }
  },
  {
    "67890-foobar" = {
      "account_id" = "67890"
      "team" = "foobar"
    }
  },
]
```

Comment: If these values are hardcoded into your locals, you could always hardcode that other `map` also. Structure transformations are more useful for dynamic input variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it:

```
map(
  flatten([
    for team, account_ids in { "foobar" = ["12345", "67890"] } : [
      for account_id in account_ids : [ 
        "${account_id}-${team}", 
        { account_id = account_id, team = team }
      ]
    ]
  ])...
)
```

`map()` takes an even number of arguments, interpreting them as `key, value, key, value, ...` so the solution is to create a list of arguments and pass them all to `map()` at once.

---

Results from the console:

```
> map(flatten([for team, account_ids in { "foobar" = ["12345", "67890"], "zazu" = ["2468", "1357"] } : [for account_id in account_ids : [ "${account_id}-${team}", { account_id = account_id, team = team }]]])...)
{
  "12345-foobar" = {
    "account_id" = "12345"
    "team" = "foobar"
  }
  "1357-zazu" = {
    "account_id" = "1357"
    "team" = "zazu"
  }
  "2468-zazu" = {
    "account_id" = "2468"
    "team" = "zazu"
  }
  "67890-foobar" = {
    "account_id" = "67890"
    "team" = "foobar"
  }
}
```